# Add bump to some part (the edge) of the procedural material

Tags: animation, texturing, materials

I was following this guide. Everything works as expected. But my final aim is to make this emission edges a bit different. I want them to be a bit heigher then other parts of the material like these chrome ornaments on this reference:

[image]

The best result that I could do looked like this. But it's not exactly what I want:

[image]

Here is my material:

[image]

So, I'm not really sure whether I chose the right track. I'm not even sure that something like this is possible :*) Help me, please, if possible <3

Comment: I don't think those metallic ornaments are made using a material (probably geometry nodes, but I'm not yet familiar with that aspect), and I doubt you can get a satisfactory result that way. (I'm also confused about the "emission" you mention, is that a misspelling?)

Comment: also i would recommend providing a link to that guide so that we know what you are talking about.

Comment: Well, the chrome parts are definitely not just bump - much too elevated, they are either displacement if done by some texture at all, but do not look like that, more like being real geometry put on there. But as the others said, I do not know what you mean with emission and I have no idea what "this guide" is either, maybe it would help to have a look at it.